# Is there a faster way to transfer data from local machine to AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I am trying to set up my very first EC2 instance for work. This work involved transferring a few large files to EC2 (around 5~10GB) every now and then. The problem is, the scp approach in the AWS document only gives me around 200~600KB/s (averaging~400), much lower than what I expected and will take me 5 hours just to upload one file.

```
scp -i /path/key-pair-name.pem /path/my-file.txt ec2-user@instance-public-dns-name:path/
```

Following similar questions here in Stackoverflow, I also tried using rsync instead with not much luck. In fact, I think it even gives a somewhat lower average speed.

```
rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh -i ${EC2_KEY}" *.safetensors "${EC2_DNS}:/home/ubuntu/"
```

Is this speed range to be expected ? Testing by basic google tool, I should have upload speed of 10Mbps, so around 1.2MB. If possible, I would love to get something over a MB. My machine is MacOS and EC2 is ubuntu. I am not the owner of this AWS account and someone else provides this EC2 instance to me, so I cannot set up an S3 and send data to it instead either.

Sorry for such a novice question and thanks you all in advance. I would really appreciate any suggestions for configurations or other approaches for faster upload speed.

(For further information) I know almost next to nothing when it comes to networking so I have no idea how to check for bottleneck in the connection. If you need any further information please write the script to check it in the comment and I will update the question with the test results.

Comment: What are the numbers that you get when running an Internet speed test from your machine? (Google has its own speed test if you don't trust arbitrary programs from the Internet; just search for "speed test").

Comment: Using the one that google provide, I got ~200Mbps download and ~10Mbps upload. I think this means my best case will only be around 10/8 ~ 1.2MB/S ?

Comment: Yes, 1.2 MB/sec is the fastest you will go. There are several reasons why you might be getting a lot less than that for actual throughput. One is that the machine is overloaded, or is a "burstable" instance; there's not much that you can do about that. The other is the connection between you and that machine might run over some very slow pipes; this is particularly likely if there's an underseas cable between you and it (I'm assuming you're in Europe by posting time; is the machine in a US zone?).

Comment: If that's the case, then *Spiff*'s answer _might_ help: you can upload to an AWS bucket that's close to you, then download to the destination machine over Amazon's backbone (which is likely to be faster than what your Internet provider will give you). That's a pain, so a better approach might be to spin up an EC2 instance near you and tunnel SSH. Only experimentation will tell.